# Forming a committee from $4$ gentlemen and $4$ ladies with conditions.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> From $4$ gentlemen and $4$ ladies a committee of $5$ is to be formed .
>    Find the no of ways of doing so if the committee consists of $1$ president,
>    $1$ vice president and $3$ secretaries?

$a.)\ ^{8}P_{5} \\
\color{green}{b.)\ 1120} \\
c.)\ ^{4}C_{2}\times ^{4}C_{3} \\
d.)\ \text{none of these}
$

I tried

$\dbinom{4+4}{1}\times \dbinom{4+4-1}{1} \times \dbinom{4+4-2}{1} \times 3!=2016 $

But that is not options.

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths up to $12$th grade.

Comment: The president can be chosen in $8$ ways, for each way the vice-president (assumed different) can be chosen in $7$ ways, and then the three secretaries (undifferentiated) can be chosen in $\binom{6}{3}$ ways.

Comment: u mean this one ?

$\dbinom{4+4}{1}\times \dbinom{4+4-1}{1} \times \dbinom{4+4-2}{3} \times 3! $

Comment: I considered $1$ instead of $3$, as I considered $3$ people as one object

Comment: Don't multiply by $3!$ at the end.  And of course we can choose the secretaries first, get $\binom{8}{3}\binom{5}{1}\binom{5}{1}$. Same number when you calculate.

Comment: The order of selection does not matter.

Comment: How do I get the idea that I have to choose secretaries before President and V-President

Comment: @RK I don't know.  How did you get that idea?  More to the point, the order of selection *of the secretaries* does not matter.

Comment: I meant that how did @AndréNicolas came up with idea that counting secreteries before President and V-P is correct but not the vice-versa .

Comment: @RK No, André's point is that it doesn't matter; which ever order you make the selection counts the same thing: ways to partition the set of eight into president, vice-president, three secretaries, and three remainders.  $\binom{8}{3}\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{1} = \binom{8}{1}\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{1}=\binom{8}{1}\binom{7}{1}\binom{6}{3}$.  When you express in terms of factorials and cancel you get a **multinomial coefficient** :$$\binom{8}{1,1,3,3} = \frac{8!}{1!\,1!\,3!\,3!}$$

Answer (score 2):

The last two factors are where you wrong.   You have counted the ways to select just one secretary then arrange three of them, somehow.   You want to count the ways to select three secretaries from the six remaining people.   The order they are selected in does not matter.